# How to use nginx to serve static html for root and proxy everything else?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

The goal with this config is:

1. Serve a plain html for the homepage to start the SPA, ex. `www.website.com`, `www.website.com/?foo=bar`
2. Proxy to the Python REST API for everything that isn't caught by 1, ex. `www.website.com/foo`, `www.website.com/foo?bar=123`

The html file is at `/var/www/website.com/index.html`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.website.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.website.com;
    access_log off;

    location = / {
        root /var/www/website.com;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

I'm seeing requests for `/index.html` on the Python side and failing there. If I delete the `location /`, then I see the "Welcome to nginx" page, so clearly the `location = /` is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NGINX - Serving Static Content](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/)

> If a request ends with a slash, NGINX treats it as a request for a directory and tries to find an index file in the directory. The index directive defines the index file’s name (the default value is index.html).

Check whether you have defined [`index`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) in the current or any enclosing scope. If so, it creates an internal redirect in nginx which will match the Python location (`location /`).

In your case I think there are at least two solutions:

1. Add another location block explicitly matching the index file:

   ```
   location = /index.html {
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Use [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) in the root location:

   ```
   location = / {
       try_files $uri $uri/index.html =404;
   }
   ```

Comment: It looks like this is exactly what's happening to me. Is there any way to directly select an html without the redirection?

Comment: Do you mean `location = /index.html {}`? That would require users to use `www.website.com/index.html` which is another problem

Comment: @DavidTan Have a look at `try_files` in the updated answer.

Comment: Solution 2 does not work as intended. As this only matches `/` the `try_files` will try the files `$root//` and then `$root//index.html`. Therefore solution 1 should be used (three locations, `= /`, `= /index.html` and `/`, together with the `index`-directive ).

Comment: @Digitalkapitaen If `$uri` doesn't exist then `$uri/index.html` will be returned. Isn't this what the OP wants?

Comment: @Cyker Technically that's not entirely correct. The variable $uri always exists. Its content in a `= /` location block can only be "/". And the `try_files`-directive does what it says, it checks if there is a file in the filesystem that matches the parameters relative to `$root`. The first parameter is `/`, which is a directory and not a file, therefore it is not used as a response. The second parameter is `//index.html`, which is also not a valid file. A try_files does not change the $uri, except for the last parameter, but in this case it is a `=404` and does not matter.

Comment: You could do something like `try_files /index.html =404` which would solve the problem and be more precise. Since the original question mentionend requests to `index.html` and it is unknown if this is the result of a `index`-directive, having an explicit `= /index.html` location is more safe.

Comment: @Digitalkapitaen `try_files /index.html =404;` works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: @Digitalkapitaen Do you mean the only difference is between `//index.html` and `/index.html`? It's very common to write `$uri/index.html` in `try_files` and nginx has `merge_slashes` turned on by default, so I don't see why they differ here.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `error_page 404` to redirect the traffic. "If there is no need to change URI and method during internal redirection it is possible to pass error processing into a named location."

Also, you had syntax errors which is why the "Welcome" page was displaying.

This solution is noted here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.website.com;
    index index.html;
    root /var/www/www.website.com;

    error_page 404 = @fallback;

    location @fallback {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is incredibly good. Since the proxy is a catch all for missing content, it makes sense for it to be the 404 handler. In turn, if the proxy cannot find it (or the proxied app returns 404),  it will simply pass *that* 404 page back to the client.